# How can see exact number of ESXI RX dropped packet and not percentage as presented in esxtop

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

esxtop shows percentage of dropped packet on different ESXI ports. Is it possible to extract the exact number of raw packets that were lost instead? If the ratio of dropped RX packets to overall RX number is very low it may still be presented as 0% I guess. Also I need for more precise packet loss investigation on ESXI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the full statistics by running

```
esxcli network port stats get -p [portid]
```

with the [portid] you see in esxtop->n, for instance.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed